# How to add more properties to each ListView element to be used in itemSelectedlistener

Tags: java, android

I have a listView with elements as movie names taken from an API.it might have duplicate names .

When the user clicks on an item it runs the onItemSelected Listener to select the movie item.

But since it can have duplicates ,instead of getting the selected Item text , i want to associate each movie item with an id , runtime etc along with the text so that when the user clicks on the field , in onItemSelected Listener I can get all the properties of the clicked item including id , moviename , runtime , release date etc ....

Whats the simplest way to do this ? Im new to android and java. Please explain ..

If I need to create a custom adapter for this , it would really help if you write a small snippet of its code.

Comment: You might want to narrow down your question if possible.  Perhaps show us the method having the problem, and include your current code.

Comment: i have updated my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should get `id`, `names`, `releaseDate`, `duration` from the api and store it in a **model/POJO** class:

```
public class Movie {

    private String id;
    private String name;
    private String year;


    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setReleaseYear(String year) {
        this.year = year;
    }

    public String getReleaseYear() {
        return year;
    }

    public String setMovieName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getMovieName() {
        return name;
    }

    public String setMovieName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

Then pass the movie object to the custom adapter.

[Here](https://www.journaldev.com/10416/android-listview-with-custom-adapter-example-tutorial) is an easy tutorial on how to set custom adapter.